# What does it mean if Google has its own links to your page displayed in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, links, backlinks

I am just curious about the following:

When viewing links to my site in Google Webmaster Tools I see all my usual links, but recently something I find strange has popped up:

Google itself is actually counting themselves as a link. Here is an example:

[image]

**My Questions:**

- Is this normal?
- Is this good?
- Is it a *dofollow* link?
- Does it mean those pages Google linked to you are likely to rank?

Comment: seems perfectly alright, somebody might have posted your links on reddit and google is able to crawl those links.

Comment: Taking your above answer into consideration, why is link coming from google then?? and not reddit, like many other links are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the domain (eg. "google.com") in the "Links to Your Site" report it will show you the pages on your site that are linked to from this domain. You can then drill down to find out from where (on "google.com") these pages are being linked from. That's the only way to really find out whether these particular links are beneficial to you.

In my experience, `google.com` links are most probably links that have been shared on Google+, the social network.

So, yes, this is normal and generally good (like any link shared on a social network).

> Is it a dofollow link?

Well, in my experience, links that are shared on Google+ are `rel="nofollow"`. However, main links in a user profile appear to be dofollow - unless they are blocked in some other way?

> Does it mean those pages google linked to are likely to rank?

If they are `nofollow` they are not going to help directly with search engine ranking. However, the social aspect of these links can help to get visitors to your site that in turn might link to and help promote your site in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this normal?

Yes it is.

> Is this good?

Yes it is.

> Is it a dofollow link?

Yes it is.

> Does it mean those pages google linked to are likely to rank?

95% sure that yes.

Comment: What evidence do you have that these links are "dofollow"? In my experience, most of these `google.com` links are the result of the URL having been shared on Google+ and appear to be `nofollow`?